# Why is optimization of dmultinom MLE falsely converging in R?

Tags: r, optimization, probability

I'm writing a Lincoln-Petersen MLE function in R. I have two versions of my distribution function, one that uses the gamma function, and one that uses Rs internal dmultinom (which uses lgamma). Both return identical results when I plug in sample values,  however the dmultinom version fails to provide acceptable MLE estimates. I'm curious as to what is causing this.

```r
llik_lincoln_multinom1 <- function(par,n_1,n_2,m_2) {
  N   <- par[1]
  p_1 <- par[2]
  p_2 <- par[3]
  q_1 <- 1-p_1
  q_2 <- 1-p_2
  r   <- n_1 + n_2 - m_2
  l   <- (gamma(sum(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r))+1)/prod(gamma(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r)+1)))*(((p_1*p_2)^m_2)*((p_1*q_2)^(n_1-m_2))*((q_1*p_2)^(n_2-m_2))*((q_1*q_2)^(N-r)))
  return(-log(l))
}
optim(par=c(20,0.1,0.1),fn=llik_lincoln_multinom1,
      n_1=10,n_2=10,m_2=2,
      lower=c(18,0,0),
      upper=c(Inf,1,1),
      method="L-BFGS-B",
      control=list(parscale=c(100,1,1)))

llik_lincoln_multinom2 <- function(par,n_1,n_2,m_2) {
  N   <- par[1]
  p_1 <- par[2]
  p_2 <- par[3]
  q_1 <- 1-p_1
  q_2 <- 1-p_2
  r   <- n_1 + n_2 - m_2
  l   <- dmultinom(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r),prob=c(p_1*p_2,p_1*q_2,q_1*p_2,q_1*q_2))
  return(-log(l))
}
optim(par=c(20,0.1,0.1),fn=llik_lincoln_multinom2,
      n_1=10,n_2=10,m_2=2,
      lower=c(18,0,0),
      upper=c(Inf,1,1),
      method="L-BFGS-B",
      control=list(parscale=c(100,1,1)))
```

In the second function, the gradient for the N parameter appears to be 0 and the MLE never moves away from the starting parameter. Why would the gradient for the second version be different than the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dmultinom(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,N-r),prob=......)` is the same as `dmultinom(c(m_2,n_1-m_2,n_2-m_2,as.integer(N-r)),prob=......)`. So a small variation of `N` does not change this value, because `as.integer(N-r)` does not change:

```
> llik_lincoln_multinom2(c(20, 0.5, 0.5), 10, 10, 2)
[1] 7.985771
> llik_lincoln_multinom2(c(20.1, 0.5, 0.5), 10, 10, 2)
[1] 7.985771
> llik_lincoln_multinom2(c(20.2, 0.5, 0.5), 10, 10, 2)
[1] 7.985771
```

So `optim` "thinks" that the first parameter, `N`, has no impact on the value of the function.

Comment: This makes sense! Is my likelihood function in the first expression then technically incorrect (even though it works), because by distribution function is not discrete? After a quick read, I was hoping to find I could adjust the ndeps control argument to assist the search, but it seems it is not so simple.

Comment: @DylanI FYI you can use the package `rgenoud` to optimize over integer parameters. I've tried with your example and it seems to work well.